# GSM PPP no internet connection

Tags: embedded, gsm, linux

I've referred to 3-4 tutorials about setting up PPP connection using GSM modem. I have a linux OS - i'll be working with this on Mint and Debian.

> https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=16325#comment-50134
>   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44597/how-to-use-internet-using-pppd-and-sim800-gsm-addon

I'm able to configure the chat scripts and the `ppp0` interface is showing up on running `ifconfig`.

But the internet doesn't work.

I've this in `/etc/networks/interfaces` to bring up ppp on boot:

```
...
...
auto rnet
iface rnet inet ppp
    provider rnet
...
```

The `syslog` shows successful connection:

```
Oct 22 17:45:33 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Oct 22 17:45:35 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: Serial connection established.
Oct 22 17:45:35 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: Using interface ppp0
Oct 22 17:45:35 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS0
Oct 22 17:45:36 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: PAP authentication succeeded
Oct 22 17:45:38 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: not replacing default route to enp0s3 [10.0.2.2]
Oct 22 17:45:38 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: local  IP address XX.XX.XX.XY
Oct 22 17:45:38 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: remote IP address 192.168.254.254
Oct 22 17:45:38 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: primary   DNS address XX.XX.XX.XX
Oct 22 17:45:38 mrid-VirtualBox pppd[808]: secondary DNS address XX.XX.XX.YY
```

and `ifconfig` gives the following response:

```
...
...
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet XX.XX.XX.XX  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.254.254
    ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
    RX packets 4  bytes 64 (64.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5  bytes 97 (97.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But the internet doesn't work. I've checked it out using AT commands for GET request that sim has internet access.

What could be the issue??

**Edit #1**

This is the result of `route` command:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp0s3
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    20101  0        0 enp0s8
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp0s8
192.168.254.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Comment: This is a system configuration question, not an electrical engineering question.  It will probably be migrated to a more appropriate site shortly.  (One possible issue might be that your setup didn't update the routing table, try the `route` command and see if there's a default via ppp0)

Comment: @ChrisStratton please tell me what would be a more appropriate site for such questions and i'll move it there :) I've also updated the result of the `route` command in the question if it helps